# What becomes the visibility of protected members in a subclass?

Tags: java, inheritance, protected

I have a class A with a protected member :

```
package p1;   
public class A{
      protected int number;
}
```

Now I've subclassed it in another package :

```
package p2;
public class B extends A{}
```

Now in the main class :

```
package p3;
public class Main{
   public static void main(String[] args){
        B b = new B();
        System.out.println(b.number);
   }
}
```

This executes perfectly. What is the visibility of protected members in subclass - do they become public ?
Then I tried following which also didn't show any error:

```
 System.out.println(new A().number);
```

After seeing this I've came to conclusion that I'm doing something really silly or misunderstood the use of `protected` specifier. The way I learnt : `protected` members can only be accessed within subclasses irrespective of packages and they remained in the same viasibilty. But the way I'm able to access the member `number` like a `public` variable even in the parent class.

Please help me understand what is happening here.

Comment: That should not work, unless `Main` is in the same package as `A`. Does the code in your post reflect your actual test?

Comment: Refer to: [Controlling Access to Members of a Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)

Comment: They don't 'become' anything. They stay what they are.

Comment: @ernest_k exactly, that should not even compile. This is actual code I stumbled upon when showing inheritance to beginners.

Comment: Seems like my IDE is buggy, cause the specifier is working fine  from command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables, methods, and constructors, which are declared protected in a superclass can be accessed only by the subclasses in other package or any class within the package of the protected members' class.

You can read more about this [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_access_modifiers.htm#:%7E:text=Protected%20Access%20Modifier%20%2D%20Protected,applied%20to%20class%20and%20interfaces.)

Comment: Seems like my IDE is buggy, cause the specifier is working fine  from command line.